# How do I cast a bool value that may be empty

Tags: c#, .net

I am pulling data from a DB and then checking whether it is true, if it is, I check the check box. The problem is that the variable may be empty and it is then throwing the error " System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."

Any Ideas?
below is the code that works well, except if it is getting an empty field.

```
if ((bool)myReader["Analytics"] == true) Analytics.Checked = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`IsDBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx) method of `DataReader`.

```
if (!myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetOrdinal("Analytics")))
{
  //not null. do your casting now.
}
```

Comment: Amazing - thanks! So just to confirm what it is now doing is: 
checking the field to make sure its not empty and then assigning the check if needed.
Why do we need to use the getOrdinal and not just getting the value of the field?

Comment: `ISDBNull` method gets a value that indicates whether the column contains non-existent or missing values. So this `if` condition checks whether that column returns a `null` or valid value, if not a `NULL`, it executes the code inside if block.  Check the link in my answer for more details(click on IsDBNull)

Comment: Because ordinal-based lookups are more efficient than named lookup.

Answer (score 1):

"Empty" values are returned as DBNull.Value so you can do something like:

```
if(myReader["Analytics"]!=DBNull.Value)
   Analytics.Checked = (bool)myReader["Analytics"];
```

As long as the column in the database is of type `bit`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var column = reader.GetOrdinal("Analytics");
if (!myReader.IsBDNull(column))
{
    Analytics.Checked = myReader.GetBoolean(column);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        object nullable=null;
        var result = (bool?)nullable;
        if(result.HasValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
Analytics.Checked = (myReader["Analytics"] == "" || (bool)myReader["Analytics"] ==  false) ? false : true );
```